# $X_n\to X$ a.s. implies $X_n\to X$ in $L^1$.

Tags: probability

Let $X_n,X\in L^1$. Does my proof work. Since $X_n\to X$ a.s., then it's uniformly bounded, and thus, by dominated convergence theorem, $\mathbb E|X_n-X|\to 0$.

Q1) Does it works ?

Q2) Also, I have the impression than even if $X_n,X\notin L^1$, $\mathbb E|X_n-X|\to 0$, no ?

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Define $X_n$ with the distribution $P(X_n=2^n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{2^n}$. These random variables are obviously in $L^1$. Using Borel-Cantelli lemma you can show that $X_n\to 0$ almost surely. However, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $E[|X_n-0|]=1$.

Comment: indeed, the upper-bound depend on $\omega $... my mistake. thank you.